# Display cut / copy / paste menu for UITextView / UITextField created programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot seem to get the default behaviour when creating a UITextView or a UITextField programmatically compared to coming from the Storyboard.

I instantiate the text view in the view controller as a property like this:

```
lazy var descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
       let tv = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
        tv.clipsToBounds = true
        tv.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        tv.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()
```

In `loadView` I add it to the view and configure auto layout. It displays correctly, so that's not the issue.

My problem is, that when selecting text within that text view, I expect the following menu being displayed (screenshot taken from a storyboard project):

[image]

What I do see though is just the menu bar showing correction proposals if single words are selected or even nothing at all when several words are selected. How can I obtain the same behaviour in my programmatic approach?

**Edit:**

Here's how I add the textview to the view (simplified, there are other views that I omitted here):

```
override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(descriptionTextView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([            
            descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            descriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            descriptionTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
            descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
        ])
}
```

When I select a single word within the textfield, I only get correction suggestions:

[image]

When I select more than one word, the menu is not popping up at all:

[image]

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue. Can you show us how you add the textView as subview? Also show us the current menu you're seeing, as what you said.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; did an edit on my original post. From what I found on the web I thought that the menu bar was default and that I needed to act if I wanted a specific menu point _not_ to be there (like to prevent cut/copy)...
As a matter of fact though, I do not have the same result when I create the textfield programmatically compared to storyboard...

Comment: Interesting problem. This shouldn't be trivial, but have you considered and tried making a fresh project, do what you're doing in your current project, start from there, see what's the difference between the two projects?

Comment: You are right: there shouldn't be an issue – I just created a new sample project from scratch and it sure does work there...

Will have to compare the two projects in this case...

Comment: If you still can't figure it out, and no one still answers your question, consider sharing your project, especially if it's not a production one. Good luck.

Comment: It's driving me nuts - even when I take the working view controller from the sample project and inject it in my project, the menu is not working any more. Conclusion: there must be a setting in a very different spot than I have been looking for so far that causes this behaviour. Will further investigate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208625/discussion-between-glenn-and-asseeger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
@objc func longPressEventHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.state == .began,
        let senderView = sender.view,
        let superView = sender.view?.superview
        else { return }

    // Make responsiveView the window's first responder
    senderView.becomeFirstResponder()

    // Set up the shared UIMenuController
    let cutMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Cut", action: #selector(cutTapped))
    let copyMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action: #selector(copyTapped))
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [cutMenuItem, copyMenuItem]

    // Tell the menu controller the first responder's frame and its super view
    UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(senderView.frame, in: superView)

    // Animate the menu onto view
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input – I cannot make it work though... I am creating the `@objc` functions `cutTapped` and `copyTapped` and add a gesture recognizer to my textview at instantiation of it with `tv.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressEventHandler(sender:))))`.
The `longPressEventHandler` is not invoked though - what am I missing?

Comment: Cal it with button event

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I introduced the problem by implementing `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` incorrectly:

actually I called `makeKeyAndVisible()` *before* setting `window?.windowScene = windowScene`.

Seems like the standard cut / copy / paste menu is contained in that property...

So, to clarify, here's `willConnectTo` *with* the mistake...:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let mainViewController = ProjectTableViewController()

let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.setViewControllers([mainViewController], animated: false)

window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.windowScene = windowScene //that's too late... :-(
```

...and here's the working code:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let mainViewController = ProjectTableViewController()

let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.setViewControllers([mainViewController], animated: false)

window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.windowScene = windowScene //that's better :-)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I know: what a stupid mistake to make – I hope my answer can help anyone else who runs into this...